# Saving images from a video camera to hard disk

Tags: c++, video, real-time

I have a Firewire camera whose driver software deposits incoming images into a circular buffer of 16 images. I would like to avoid re-buffering these images, and just write them as fast as possible to disk. So I would prefer to just enqueue a pointer to each buffer as it is filled, and have a separate disk write thread which kept far enough ahead of the incoming images to be confident that it would write them out to disk before the incoming images overwrote them.

Clearly this would depend on the image size and frame rate... but in principle, for VGA images at 30 frames per second, we're talking about needing to write 27.6 MB/sec. This seems quite achievable, particularly if the writing thread can decide to drop occasional frames to keep far enough ahead of the incoming images, and if this strategy fails, to at least detect that an overwrite has invalidated the image, and signal that appropriately (e.g. delete the file after completion).

Comments on the validity of this strategy are welcome... but what I really want to know is what disk writing functions should be used for maximum efficency to get the disk writing rate up as high as possible. E.g. CreateFile() using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING + WriteFile()?

Comment: maybe this could be done with ofstream. How does you driver fill the array?

Comment: Data from the camera is (I believe) DMA'd into memory with no discernible impact on the CPU. There is only one write thread - I don't know what gives the idea that I would use multiple threads.

Comment: @omatai Oh, I'm sorry, reading it again I don't know either, I must have imagined that for some reason :)